# Decrypt hex strings using 3DES in Ruby from .NET

Tags: ruby, encryption, 3des

I'm working on a Ruby project that is interacting with a webservice that I'm exchanging some encrypted data with.

I am having a very hard time decrypting something I get back from the webservice in Ruby, although in the .NET side, it's working fine, and a number of other web-based or desktop-based tools can deal with this.

The encryption method was 3DES with ECB and no padding.

Below is a test script I have been working on.  I've tried everything I can think of to get these strings unpacked correctly, but to no avail.

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

def cipher(key, encrypted)
  key = key.unpack('a2'*32).map{|x| x.hex}.pack('c'*32)
  encrypted = encrypted.unpack('a2'*32).map{|x| x.hex}.pack('c'*32)
  OpenSSL::Cipher::ciphers.select{|c| c.include? 'des3' }.map do |cipher_name|
    begin
      cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new(cipher_name)
      cipher.padding = 0
      cipher.decrypt
      cipher.key=key

      plain = cipher.update(encrypted) + cipher.final

      p "Cipher #{cipher_name} success: #{plain} #{plain.class} #{plain.length} #{plain.encoding.to_s}"
      plain
    rescue => e
      p "Cipher #{cipher_name} failed #{e}"
      nil
    end
  end

end

key = '202FA9B21843D7022B6466DB68327E1F'
encrypted = 'ff6f07e270ebd5c0878c67c999d87ebf'

res1 = cipher key, encrypted

key = '49CE85147B24123718AB3F4539AB1A21'
encrypted = '995604ed8016da8897f1875ebd725529'

res2 = cipher key, encrypted


p res1 == res2 ? "SUCCESS" : "FAIL"

# In both cases, the correct output should be '25588015543912470222703296730936'
```

[image: BC-Tools Decryption]

Comment: "3DES with ECB and no padding", wow, what a bad combination! Do not use 3DES unless it must be used for compatibility with a legacy system and the legacy system can not be changed. Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin. Use CBC with a random IV, prepend the IV to the encrypted data.

If the input data is not always a multiple of the block size then padding must be added to the input data; specify padding, PKCS#5 is the preferred padding for DES/3DES.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I agree, and would not be doing it if it were avoidable.

Comment: Ah yes, actual security is not all that important, there always seem to be  excuses that take precedent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 3DES key is 24-bytes, use a full length key.

3DES uses triple encryption with essentially a 24-byte key. `202FA9B21843D7022B6466DB68327E1F` is hex encoded 16-byte key.

Try repeating the first 8-bytes of the key:
`202FA9B21843D7022B6466DB68327E1F202FA9B21843D702`

Some 3DES implementations will repeat 8-bytes of a 16-byte key but relying on such implementation details is not a good idea.

Note: 3DES actually uses a 168-bit key because the LSb of each byte is not used. Further because there are actually three DES calls the security is only 112-bits. Additionally DES has some weak keys. There are two common modes, ede and ded, in an effort to facilitate moving from DES to 3DES thus adding more confusion.

Finally: Move from 3DES to AES in CBC mode with a random IV. Please don't continue poor security practices.

Comment: Thank you - it looks like this is it.  The confusion came from openssl zero-padding the remainder of the key, whereas the "host" implementation uses the strategy of repeating the first bytes.

Comment: I will let the "host" end of this interchange know that a lot of the security around this is pretty awful and hope I can get them to change.  And in the mean time, I learned a bunch about encryption yesterday.